# How to configure netbeans 8.0.2 for C++ in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, c++, netbeans, g++, compiler

I am new to programming, netbeans and ubuntu. I have **installed the netbeans ide** with the c/c++ bundle from https://netbeans.org/downloads/ . I have no idea what else to install. Please help me in installing the compliers and the things required for starting to code.

Comment: I did that with 64 bit netBeans ID on Ubuntu 18.04 64bits and it did not work. It can not find compiler c/c++. I checked if the compilers are in 18.04 and they are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need (including compilers) comes in that NetBeans IDE package.

You should probably read this guide which will show you how to create a new project and run code: [C/C++ Projects Quick Start Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html)

In NetBeans IDE press <kbd>F1</kbd> for more documentation.

Comment: Than you very much. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Netbeans website](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads) if you specifically want to install only the C/C++ bundle you can do it from choosing from the options, else select all to download the entire package.

Because Ubuntu comes with pre-installed compiler GCC you need not to install a one.

After the download is complete. Open terminal go to the downloads directory:

```
cd downloads
chmod +x netbeans-8.2-cpp-linux-x86.sh
./netbeans-8.2-cpp-linux-x86.sh
```

Because I downloaded only the C/C++ bundle, hence is the name you name can change according to the package you chose for.